# How to stop cupcakes from collapsing?

Tags: baking, cake, pastry

I made two kinds of cupcakes recently from [Who You Callin' Cupcake?](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1569757399) and both of them collapsed in the center.

The cupcake that collapsed the most was the Devil's Food Cupcake. This contained:

- all-purpose flour
- sugar
- cocoa powder
- baking soda
- salt
- canola oil
- vinegar
- vanilla
- hot coffee

I baked them in a dark cupcake pan with white paper liners. Why did this collapse and how can I stop this?

Comment: Did it seem done in the center?  Collapsing and done vs. collapsing and wet have different reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One strong possibility is that the recipe is overleavened, which will cause it to blow up fast and then collapse. [BakeWise (by Shirley Corriher)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416560785) recommends 1 teaspoon baking powder or 1/4 teaspoon baking soda per cup of flour as a guideline. If your recipe is much beyond that, suspect that is the issue.

Comment: This can be especially true depending on your altitude.  Most recipes are written from sea level, but as the altitude increases, the atmospheric pressure decreases, so less leavening is needed.